# data from http request to convert string to list of LatLng in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-ios, flutter-android, fluttermap

```
String  map = widget.list[widget.index]['map'];
```

example for `"[LatLng(12.82879876203614, 80.12908793985844),LatLng(12.83370395257544, 80.1245865225792),LatLng(12.839642030904889, 80.12061484158039),]"`
the data of map is now string but I want LatLng format ( without "" Double Quotation ) like `[LatLng(12.82879876203614, 80.12908793985844),LatLng(12.83370395257544, 80.1245865225792),LatLng(12.839642030904889, 80.12061484158039),]`

```
     Set<Polygon> polygonSet = new Set();
  polygonSet.add(Polygon(
      polygonId: PolygonId('test'),
      points: map,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeColor: Colors.blue,
      fillColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),));

  return polygonSet;
}
```

the out put error: `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'LatLng'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonDecode() to convert the String to List of LatLng.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String map =
      '"[LatLng(12.82879876203614, 80.12908793985844),LatLng(12.83370395257544, 80.1245865225792),LatLng(12.839642030904889, 80.12061484158039),]"';
  List<LatLng> latlngList = jsonDecode(map);
  print(latlngList);
}
```

And the output will be :

```
[LatLng(12.82879876203614, 80.12908793985844),LatLng(12.83370395257544, 80.1245865225792),LatLng(12.839642030904889, 80.12061484158039),]
```

Comment: Unexpected character (at character 2)
[LatLng(12.82879876203614, 80.12908793985844),LatLng(12.83370395257544, 80....
 ^

it show's  error

Comment: _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<LatLng>')